# Multiple volume and progress control JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have a page with several audio tracks, like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/24eLsv6r/2/

The problem is that the volume and progress controls are attached *only* to the first audio.
I tried parenting them with something like:

```
$vol = $('volume', $(this).parent())[0];
```

And

```
$bar = $('progressbar', $(this).parent())[0];
```

But it's still isn't working.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: That is not a proper jQuery selector. `volume` and `progressbar` are not html tags. `progress` is in HTML5.

Comment: So, you're suggesting something like: 
`$bar = $('progress', $(this).parent())[0];` ?

Comment: those are class names, just add a dot before the classname`$vol = $('.volume',//..`

Comment: The real problem is that your `progress` function is based on `$aud[0]`, which is a single element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through in each audio using jQuery.each(). In this context you can get and set the control independently.

I added IDs just to prove a solution. (volume1, prog1...)

I made a solution that could help you. It's CSS3 valid.

**HTML**

```
<div class="player">
    <audio class="audio" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Common_Pauraque_VOL_11-05_Dudley_T._Dougherty_Natural_Sounds_Collection.ogg" loop>
        <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
    </audio>
    <div class="playpause"></div>
    <div id="volume0" class="volume"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="prog0" class="progressbar"></div>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="player">
    <audio class="audio" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Common_Pauraque_VOL_11-05_Dudley_T._Dougherty_Natural_Sounds_Collection.ogg" loop>
        <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
    </audio>
    <div class="playpause"></div>
    <div id="volume1" class="volume"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="prog1" class="progressbar"></div>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="player">
    <audio class="audio" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Common_Pauraque_VOL_11-05_Dudley_T._Dougherty_Natural_Sounds_Collection.ogg" loop>
        <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
    </audio>
    <div class="playpause"></div>
    <div id="volume2" class="volume"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="prog2" class="progressbar"></div>
    <br>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .player {
        position: relative;
        margin: 50px auto;
        text-align: center;
        width: 300px;
    }
    .playpause {
        background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/WikiWidgetPlayButton.png) no-repeat center;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 7px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        padding: 12px 0;
    }
    .playpause:hover {
        border-color: #ccc;
    }
    .playing {
        background: url(http://www.pokeroffice.com/img/manual/pause.gif) no-repeat center;
    }
    .volume, .progressbar {
        border: none;
        height: 2px;
    }
    .volume {
        background: hsla(120, 55%, 50%, 1);
        color: inherit;
    }
    .progressbar {
        background: grey;
        color: inherit;
    }
    .ui-slider-handle {
        border-radius: 50% !important;
        height: 11px !important;
        margin-left: -5px !important;
        top: -5px !important;
        width: 15px !important;
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    var $aud = $(".audio"),
        $pp = $(".playpause");

    $aud.each(function (i, audio) {
        var $bar = $("#prog" + i);
        var $vol = $("#volume" + i);
        var AUDIO = $aud[i];

        AUDIO.volume = 0.15;
        AUDIO.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {

            $bar.slider("value", ~~ (100 / AUDIO.duration * AUDIO.currentTime));
        }, false);

        $vol.slider({
            value: AUDIO.volume * 100,
            slide: function (ev, ui) {
                $vol.css({
                    background: "hsla(180," + ui.value + "%,50%,1)"
                });
                AUDIO.volume = ui.value / 100;
            }
        });

        $bar.slider({
            value: AUDIO.currentTime,
            slide: function (ev, ui) {
                AUDIO.currentTime = AUDIO.duration / 100 * ui.value;
            }
        });
    });

    $pp.click(function () {
        $aud = $("audio", $(this).parent())[0];
        if ($aud.paused) {
            $(this).addClass("playing");
            $aud.play();
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("playing");
            $aud.pause();
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/ofajs4og/2/)